# Math behind leetcode problem 47 permutations II

Tags: algorithms, permutations, c++

Please tell me why the expression `i>0 && nums[i] == nums[i-1] && !used[i-1]` works on getting unique permutations. And what is the math behind it?
The problem is as follows:
Given a collection of numbers that might contain duplicates, return all possible unique permutations.
Example:

```
Input: [1,1,2]
Output:
[
  [1,1,2],
  [1,2,1],
  [2,1,1]
]
```

Here is the code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> permuteUnique(vector<int>& nums) {   
        vector<vector<int>> result; 
        vector<int> temp;
        vector<bool> used(nums.size(), false);
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        backtrack(nums, temp, result, used);
        return result;        
    }
    
    void backtrack(vector<int>& nums, vector<int>& temp, vector<vector<int>>& result, vector<bool>& used){
        
        if(temp.size() == nums.size()){
            result.emplace_back(temp);
        }else{
            
            for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++){
                if(used[i] || i>0 && nums[i] == nums[i-1] && !used[i-1]) continue; 
                used[i] = true;
                temp.push_back(nums[i]);
                backtrack(nums, temp, result, used);
                used[i] = false;
                temp.pop_back();
            }            
        }        
    }    
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You are sorting the vector so duplicate values will be consecutively present in the vector.

(2) Now we come to the logic behind that condition:

- As the vector can contain the duplicates we should make sure not to repeat the same sequence by starting with the same element again(duplicate)

  - example :

    - `1,1,2` (starting with `first` one) and 1,1,2 (starting with `second` one) => both are same (we should make sure this doesn't happen)

Example: In `[1, 1, 2]`

- If the first element in the sequence is chosen as 1, then we should make sure we are not going to create another sequence starting with another 1 (duplicate of the element).
- So for that, we need to skip the loop for all the consecutive duplicate elements.
- In your case, after creating a sequence staring with first 1, when we enter the loop for the second time we check whether the current element is a duplicate `nums[i] == nums[i - 1]` (this is sufficient as you have already sorted the vector) and whether the current element is the first element of the sequence `!used[i - 1]`.

  - In your case, due to this condition, the second one cannot be the first element of the sequence.